# Entity metadata for Role#users was not found

Tags: typeorm, typegraphql

Trying to make `OneToMany` and `ManyToOne` relationship with TypeORM but I get this error, I don't know what's wrong with my code.

I have the following User entity:

```ts
import { BaseEntity, Column, Entity, ManyToOne, PrimaryGeneratedColumn } from 'typeorm';
import { Field, ID, ObjectType } from 'type-graphql';

import { Role } from './';

@ObjectType()
@Entity()
export class User extends BaseEntity {
  @Field(() => ID)
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  public id: number;

  @Field()
  @Column('text', { unique: true })
  public userName: string;

  @Column()
  public password: string;

  @Field()
  @Column('boolean', { default: true })
  public isActive: boolean;

  @ManyToOne(() => Role, role => role.users)
  @Field(() => Role, { nullable: true })
  public role: Role;
}
```

Role entity:

```ts
import { BaseEntity, Column, Entity, OneToMany, PrimaryGeneratedColumn } from 'typeorm';
import { Field, ID, ObjectType } from 'type-graphql';

import { User } from '.';

@ObjectType()
@Entity()
export class Role extends BaseEntity {
  @Field(() => ID)
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  public id: number;

  @Field()
  @Column('text', { unique: true })
  public name: string;

  @OneToMany(() => User, user => user.role, { lazy: false })
  @Field(() => [User], { nullable: true })
  public users: User[];
}
```

However I keep getting this error

```
(node:4541) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Entity metadata
for Role#users was not found. Check if you specified a correct entity
object and if it's connected in the connection options. [1]     at
/node_modules/typeorm/metadata-builder/EntityMetadataBuilder.js:571:23
[1]     at Array.forEach (<anonymous>) [1]     at
EntityMetadataBuilder.computeInverseProperties
(/node_modules/typeorm/metadata-builder/EntityMetadataBuilder.js:567:34)
[1]     at
/node_modules/typeorm/metadata-builder/EntityMetadataBuilder.js:80:74
[1]     at Array.forEach (<anonymous>) [1]     at
EntityMetadataBuilder.build
(/node_modules/typeorm/metadata-builder/EntityMetadataBuilder.js:80:25)
[1]     at ConnectionMetadataBuilder.buildEntityMetadatas
(/node_modules/typeorm/connection/ConnectionMetadataBuilder.js:57:141)
[1]     at Connection.buildMetadatas
(/node_modules/typeorm/connection/Connection.js:494:57)
[1]     at Connection.<anonymous>
(/node_modules/typeorm/connection/Connection.js:126:30)
[1]     at step
(/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:136:27) [1]
(node:4541) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise
rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async
function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was
not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1) [1] (node:4541) [DEP0018]
DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In
the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the
Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: "Entity metadata was not found" also shows up when you forget to add the `@Entity` annotation on one of the entities. The entities also have to be declared in the "entities" section of your connection setup (see answer from @Martin Konicek).

Comment: For me I add entity relation, importing the connected entities fixed it

Answer (score 150):

I am using [NestJS](https://nestjs.com/) with PostgreSQL and I had the same issue. The problem was by me is that I forgot to import the entity in the module with the `TypeOrmModule.forFeature` function.

```js
@Module({
  imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([Users, ...])],  <--- Importing the entity!
  controllers: [...],
  providers: [...],
  exports: [...],
})
```

Comment: just an add: I did the same error running tests, because even in tests you may take care of this entities if you are testing with database

Comment: This answer ought to be accepted.

Answer (score 56):

If you still have the issue after applying the other solutions presented here. Check if your entities have the `@Entity()` decorator. I was missing this and after adding it it solved the issue.

Also adding `autoLoadEntities: true` in the connection options was needed.

Answer (score 47):

This just means that your entities are either not loading, or are loading incorrectly

You need to fix the loading of your entities. Entities will usually be loaded from the `ormconfig.js` file

Just create a file `ormconfig.js` and type something like this, *emphasis on the entities*

```js
module.exports = {
  "name": "default",
  "type": "mongodb",
  "host": "localhost",
  "port": "27017",
  "username": "root",
  "password": "",
  "database": "rocketlaunches",
  "entities": [
    __dirname + "entities/**/*.entity.ts"
  ]
}
```

Now obviously, you would load your entities from wherever they are on your project

Comment: Good answer, remind me to check that *.entity.ts file name, Thinks.

Comment: didn't think to need the full path. Seeing the __dirname saved me a lot of sanity.

Comment: It work for me. I was call all entities as `__dirname + "/entities/*.ts"` and it works. Before i got error for this `__dirname + "entities/*.ts"` or `__dirname + "./entities/*.ts"`.

Comment: This also reminded me to check my file names. I had a typo for `.entity.ts`.

Answer (score 19):

I ran into the same issue.

TypeORM is very difficult to debug with args and meta data classes/collections all over the place. After many hours I was able to figure it out.

So this relationship is failing because EntityMetadataBuilder.ts is trying to tie the type of the ManyToOne column with a known entity type using `===`.

```js
var inverseEntityMetadata = entityMetadatas.find(function (m) {
  return m.target === relation.type || 
    (typeof relation.type === "string" && m.targetName === relation.type); 
});
```

Looking at relation.type I could see that it is the same "type" as `m.target` however they were not pointing to the same reference of the defined type. It seemed to me as if my related class was being loaded by node more than once. After reading about how node caches modules I was able to fix my problem by making sure all of my `import` statements were referencing the same file including uppercase/lowercase letters in the string.

In one file I had

```js
import { Transaction } from "./transaction";
```

and the other I had

```js
import { Transaction } from "./Transaction";
```

Notice the uppercase "t". After replacing with a lowercase "T" everything worked as expected.

Comment: Debugging doesn't have to be difficult. If you simply add a `console.log(relation.type); console.log(entityMetadatas);`, you'll see that it's looking for `[Function: Table]` in an array with values that should include `target: [Function: Table]` (in the case where the relation is specified as a function). If entityMetadatas doesn't have a value with that target, then the entity is missing from `createConnection`

Comment: I saw this comment at github. Even both were different.

Comment: Had to rename to `transactionz.ts` temporarily, then back to `transaction.ts` to get the file system to be in sync with the lower case.

Answer (score 13):

In my project TypeORM is initialized like this:

```
import { createConnection } from 'typeorm';

const conn = await createConnection({
  // Make sure to specify all entities here
  entities: [User, Role],

  // ... More options
})
```

Just need to make sure that `entities` lists all your entities.

(This is the alternative if you're not using `ormconfig.js` to specify entities.)

Answer (score 8):

For my case, I was missing the `@Entity()` on top of my class,
check if all your classes have the `@Entity()` decorator

Answer (score 6):

I faced this problem, in my case, the solution is to remove the dist folder inside the server

Comment: yes, it indeed worked, because you added new entities causing the issue.

Comment: +1 Very related for me. I initially named my file `Upload.ts` then renamed to `upload.ts`. In the `dist` folder it renamed `Upload.js` & `Upload.map`. I had to rename the file to `uploadz.ts`, update all imports, and purge the dist folder. Then I could rename back to `upload.ts`.

Comment: This solved it for me. I renamed some entities and modified the migration files accordingly, but the dist folder needed to be deleted.

Answer (score 5):

in my case, I solved it by adding the Role entity. to the entity array in the main app.module class. I initially forgot to add it.

```
TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
  type: process.env.DB_TYPE as any,
  host: process.env.DB_HOST,
  port: parseInt(process.env.DB_PORT),
  username: process.env.DB_USERNAME,
  password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
  database: process.env.DB_NAME,
  entities: [User, Role],
  synchronize: true,
```

Answer (score 4):

This could mean that your entities are either not loading, or are loading incorrectly. One mistake could be you are not including the word "entity" in your file name. The correct naming is "user.entity.ts" or "role.entity.ts"

Comment: Forgetting to include `entity` in the filename was my issue.

Answer (score 3):

My problem was that I was using node-ts to run only the typescript files for my project. However, my build still emitted .js files that were ignored/hidden. I don't know why, but cleaning out the *.js and *.js.map compiled files worked. What's strange is my ormconfig only specifies .ts files.

I recommend adding the `"noEmit": true` to tsconfig.json compiler options to prevent any future headaches with a similar approach.

Comment: It worked for me after deleted `/dist` folder, the destination of transpiled JS files from TypeScript

Answer (score 3):

check that the files have the word `entity` in their name.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 3):

in my case I forgot to add the .entity part to the file
file name was: `user.ts`
where it should have been: `user.entity.ts`
because in my config file I look for files ending with .entity.ts as my entities.

```
entities: [__dirname + '/**/*.entity.{ts,js}'],
```

Answer (score 3):

possible causes:

- you forgot to import your entity's module into `AppModule.imports[]`, alternatively set `autoLoadEntities: true`
- you forgot to add the decorator `@Entity()` to your entity class
- you moved the entity file so it no longer matches `**/entities/*.entity.ts`
- you forgot to add the entity to `TypeOrmModule.forFeature()`

Answer (score 2):

In my project deleting dist solves the issue.

Answer (score 2):

After trying the solutions above ( delete the dist, put the @Entity() decorator, look for maybe a wrong import in the case of capital letter in one file and not in the other), I just disable the **autoLoadEntities** and import manually all of my entities in the entities field.

NB : In the config.ts file, I got a class AppConstant in which all of my useful constants are declared Like DB_CONFIG shown in this pic.

[config.ts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xy4i2.png)
[image]

And in the app.module.ts, I make this :

In sum, It's just an typeOrm import error so this is what I did to solve this issue

[app.module.ts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/taf6q.png)
[image]

Answer (score 2):

For me, the issue was that I was using the Entity decorator without the `@` so I just changed `Entity();` to `@Entity()` and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem because I accidentally deleted my RoleModule "role.module.ts". When I recreated the module the problem was easelly solved.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I keep doing the same mistake over and over. In typeorm config I specify to look for `dist/**/*.model.js` files.

But every now and then I have this brilliant idea to start using `*.entity.ts`    suffix, resulting in the above error.

Renaming file to `xx.model.ts` fixes it.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I solved with:

autoLoadEntities: true,

in app.module.ts

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I'm using NestJS and MySQL. I also faced this issue and I checked for `@Entity`, filenames etc.
What I found was that when we list all the entities for

```
TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
  useFactory: () => ({
    ...remainingConfigs,
    entities: [...allEntities],
  })
})
```

The order in which entities are listed is a bit important in case when there exists a relationship between them.
For Example, if `UserEntity` contains `@JoinColumn` for `DepartmentEntity`, then `DepartmentEntity` should be listed before `UserEntity`.

I know this question isn't active, but I just wanted to share this possibility with everyone since it took quite some time.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I correctly had place the TypeOrm.forFeature([Denom]) in the DenomModule, but I was missing the entity in the main module:

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
      type: "postgres",
      host: "localhost",
      port: 5432,
      username: "postgres",
      password: "postgres",
      database: "testnestjs",
      entities: [.., Denom],
      synchronize: true
    }),
    DenomModule,
    ...,
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I forgot to decorate one of my entities with @Entity decorator. Silly one but I thought it might help some one.

Answer (score 0):

Although this question was already answered, I encountered the same problem using typeorm with NestJS and the problem was a combination of multiple factors. You have to ensure that multiple conditions are met, depending on whether you use TypeOrm with Nestjs or not.

1. Your entities must be decorated with `@Entity` decorator imported from typeorm library. (Which in the example above, is correct). This has to be ensured in both cases, with or without NestJS.

Steps for TypeOrm without NestJS:

2. Include all the entities in `entities` property in your typeorm connection. This could be in `createConnection` method or in `DataSource` constructor, depending on your typeorm version. You can either explicitly list them:

```
...
username: process.env.DB_USER,
password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
entities: [User, Role]
...
```

... or you can use a regex and name your files with `entity.ts` suffix, which in my opinion is the better way, because you don't have to change the file if you later add or delete an entity:

```
...
username: process.env.DB_USER,
password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
entities: [__dirname + '/**/*.entity.{js,ts}'],
...
```

This should do the work if you use TypeOrm without NestJS.

Steps for usage in NestJS:

2. Include the entities in `TypeOrmModule.forRoot` call, just like in step 2. of non-Nestjs approach.
3. Include entities in their respective `TypeOrmModule.forFeature` call in the module they belong to.

```
@Module({
    imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([User, Role...]), ...],
...
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue happened randomly to me between 2 file saves. I didn't solved it by updating `entities` key (it was set to `[__dirname + '/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}']`) or enabling `autoLoadEntities`, but by downgrading my typeorm version to `0.2.22`.

Check this issue for more info : https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/5676

Answer (score 0):

When I had this issue, I had my `entities` missing one entity.

```
export const AppDataSource = new DataSource({
    type: "postgres",
    host: "localhost",
    port: 5432,
    username: "postgres",
    password: "postgres",
    database: "typeormtest",
    synchronize: true,
    logging: false,
    entities: [Member, Task, Committee ], // i had "committee" mia
    subscribers: [],
    migrations: [],
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue, just make sure the module that contains your entity is included in imports of **AppModule** like so:

```
@Module({
  imports: [
  
    XXModule,
    YYModule
  ],
  controllers: [],
  providers: [],
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Checkout possible circular dependency issues. It is hard to find but you may try to referencing absolute paths in the files those import the new files you have created or modifed existed. A circular dependency issue in typeorm causes some of unrelative entities are not loaded.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was because I forgot to do `dataSource.initialize()`

I faced this when I was testing, and I have this habit of just returning the value. It is later when I use them in other function then I have to use `dataSource.initialize()`.

Apparently if you don't do this, you can console log `dataSource` and see it nicely. **Except**, that it has an empty array on `entityMetadata` property. Once you initialize it you can console log it again and see that the `entityMetadata` property has a lot of values.

Then if you want to use something like `dataSource.manager.save(<your entity instance>)` you can do it normally.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Ensure all files are written in lowercase (do not use both uppercase and lowercase letters in the Entity file names)
> 2. lowercase in filesystem and in entity file

```
import { User } from './user'; // all files in lowcase!
```

> 3. Check paths to entity in main app module! (also path in DIST folder for entities

```
entities: [__dirname + '/typeorm/entities/*.{ts,js}']
```

> Here is ready relation

```
 @Module({
      imports: [
        ConfigModule.forRoot({
          envFilePath: '.dev.env',
        }),
        TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
          imports: [ConfigModule],      
          useFactory: (configService: ConfigService) => ({
            type: 'mysql',
            host: configService.get<string>('DATABASE_HOST')            || 'host.com',
            port: parseInt(configService.get<string>('DATABASE_PORT')   || '3306'),
            username: configService.get<string>('DATABASE_USER')        || 'xxx',
            password: configService.get<string>('DATABASE_PASS')        || 'xxx',
            database: configService.get<string>('DATABASE_NAME')        || 'xxx',
            entities: [__dirname + '/typeorm/entities/*.{ts,js}'],
            synchronize: true,
            autoLoadEntities: true,
          }),
          inject: [ConfigService],
        }),
        Users,
        Othermod
      ],
      controllers: [AppController],
      providers: [AppService],
    })
```

> 4. Check Entity in your new Modules

/src/users/users.module.ts

```
// bla bla bla
  
    import { Profile } from '../typeorm/entities/profile';
    import { Posts } from '../typeorm/entities/posts';
    import { Booking } from '../typeorm/entities/booking';
    import { Files } from '../typeorm/entities/files';
    
     // used Entities in Module
    const entityMod = [
      Profile,
      Posts,
      Booking,
      Files
    ];
    
    
    @Module({
      imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature(entityMod)],
      controllers: [UsersController],
      providers: [UsersService],
    })
    export class UsersModule {}
```

> 5. Use typeORM "const" console for Debug

```
console.log(relation.type); 
console.log(entityMetadatas);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was missing an entity, specified in the error in `entities` argument object param, passed to `new DataSource` constructor.

Try to debug `entities` array to make sure, that your entity is present.