# Error: Object metadata not found after adding many-to-many relationships

Tags: typeorm

I need to have additional properties for many-to-many relationships, I created a new entity myself as shown in the documentation.

https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/many-to-many-relations.md#many-to-many-relations-with-custom-properties

It's user entity.

```
import { Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, Column, OneToMany } from 'typeorm';
import { ShareTask } from './../../share-taks/entity/share-taks.entity';

@Entity('users')
export class User {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    public id: number;

    @Column({ type: 'varchar', nullable: false })
    public email: string;

    @Column({ type: 'varchar', nullable: false })
    public password: string;

    @OneToMany(() => ShareTask, (shareTask: ShareTask) => shareTask.user)
    public shareTask: ShareTask[];
}
```

It's task entity.

```
import { Entity, Column, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, OneToMany } from 'typeorm';
import { ShareTaks } from './../../share-taks/entity/share-taks.entity';

@Entity('tasks')
export class Taks {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    public id: number;

    @Column({ type: 'varchar', nullable: false, length: 50 })
    public title: string;

    @OneToMany(() => ShareTaks, (shareTaks: ShareTaks) => shareTaks.taks)
    public shareTaks: ShareTaks[];    
}
```

It's ormconfig.json.

```
{
    "type": "mysql",
    "host": "localhost",
    "port": 3306,
    "username": "root",
    "password": "7047",
    "database": "db",
    "entities": ["dist/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}"],
    "synchronize": true
}
```

It's ShareTaks entity.

```
import { Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, Column, ManyToOne } from 'typeorm';
import { User } from './../../users/entity/user.entity';
import { Taks } from './../../taks/entity/taks.entity';

@Entity('shareTasks')
export class shareTask {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    public id: number;

    @Column({ type: 'integer', nullable: false })
    public taskId: number;

    @Column({ type: 'integer', nullable: false })
    public userId: number;

    @ManyToOne(() => (task: Task) => task.shareTask, { cascade: ['insert', 'update', 'remove'] })
    public task: Task;

    @ManyToOne(() => (user: User) => user.shareTask, { cascade: ['insert', 'update', 'remove'] })
    public user: User;
}
```

Before I made a many-to-many relationship, everything worked well. When I added a many-to-many relationship, I get an error.

> Error: Entity metadata for ShareTask#task was not found. Check if you specified a correct entity object and if it's connected in the connection options.

Because of what I get an error, I can’t understand.

I found some answers to my question, but they did not help me.

[Entity metadata for Role#users was not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56693067/entity-metadata-for-roleusers-was-not-found)

https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/420

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Likely, the error is caused by the path you provided in the entities in ormconfig file. Try changing it to a relative path from the current directory, something like

```
"entities": [__dirname + "/../**/*.entity{.ts,.js}"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by exporting from an index, and then importing from that index in both my User and Role file.  When I was importing directly from the class files I was getting the this error.

> Error during server startup TypeORMError: Entity metadata for User#role_id was not found. Check if you specified a correct entity object and if it's connected in the connection options.

My guess is that the strict equals (===) is colliding with a cache and thinking that the different relative import paths refer to different classes.

src/entities/index.ts:

```
import Team from "./Team";
import Role from "./Role";
import User from "./User";
    
export { Team, Role, User };
```

DataService.ts (where the datasources are defined)

```
import { Role, Team, User } from "../entities";
...
entities: [Role, Team],
...
```

src/entities/User.ts

```
import { Team, Role } from "../entities";
...
@Column()
@IsNotEmpty()
@ManyToOne(() => Role, (role) => role.id)
role_id: number;
```